# took this directly from book - doesn't work

Tags: jquery, arrays, forms, serialization

I'm doing some examples from a book called jQUery, jQuery UI, and jQuery Mobile Recipes and Examples by Adriaan de Jonge and Phil Dutson. This is supposed to be a simple way to display form contents on a page. Unless I have a typo, I have no idea why it's not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<title>form test</title>
</head>
<body>


<form action="" method="post">
    <label for="first_field">First field</label>
    <input type="text" name="first_field" value="" id="first_field"><br>
    <label for="second_field">second field</label>
    <input type="text" name="second_field" value="" id="second_field"><br>
    <label for="third_field">third field</label>
    <input type="text" name="third_field" value="" id="third_field"><br>
    <label for="fourth_field">fourth field</label>
    <input type="text" name="fourth_field" value="" id="fourth_field"><br>
</form>

    <input type="button" name="serialize-array" value="serializeArray" id="serialize-array">                
    <input type="button" name="serialize" value="Serialize" id="serialize">

<hr>
<div id="placeholder"></div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$('serialize').click(function() {
$('#placeholder').html($('form').serialize());
});


$('serialize-array').click(function() {
$('#placeholder').html(JSON.stringify(
$('form').serializeArray()));
});

});
</script>

<hr>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "Unless I have a typo, I have no idea why it's not working." That's why.

Comment: Even books can have typo too

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be missing `id` selector.

`$('serialize')` supposed to be `$('#serialize')`

```
  ^----  Missing Here
```

`$('serialize-array')` supposed to be `$('#serialize-array')`

```
  ^----  Missing Here
```

**Code**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#serialize').click(function () {
        $('#placeholder').html($('form').serialize());
    });


    $('#serialize-array').click(function () {
        $('#placeholder').html(JSON.stringify(
        $('form').serializeArray()));
    });

});
```

Comment: Hey I upvoted it too. Why I'm even getting any at all is beyond me :/ Sorry Sushanth

Comment: #seriously?  Ha! thanks - that was wicked fast.

Answer (score 4):

`$('serialize-array')` needs to be like `$('#serialize-array')`, same with `serialize`. Missing the `#`.

Comment: you guys are crazy fast